# Performance vs Slightly Cleaner Code: checking attribute before vs during loop

Tags: java

I am adding some changes to existing code and noticed that it could *possibly* be optimized by checking a condition before hand, however doing so does make the code as clean.

The original code was something like this:

```
private void changeProperties(String a, String b, Document doc) {
    if(!isEmptyOrNull(a)) {
        doc.setA(a);
    }
    if(!isEmptyOrNull(b)){
        doc.setB(b);
    }
    saveDocument(doc);
}
```

And then I added a method would simply take in a list and call the above method, like so

```
private void updatePropertiesForDocuments(List<Document> docs, String a, String b) {
    docs.forEach(doc -> changeProperties(a, b, doc));
}
```

I then realized that, in the new functionality, that the attributes 'a' and 'b' will always be the same for each document. With this information, I thought that it is pretty pointless to check if 'a' and 'b' are null or empty for every single document (esepcially if the list can be quite large, such as 100,000+).

So then I thought it would be a better idea to just do the null checks before entering the loop like so:

```
private void updatePropertiesForDocuments(List<Document> docs, String a, String b) {
    boolean isAMissing = isEmptyOrNull(a);
    boolean isBMissing = isEmptyOrNull(b);

    if(!isAMissing && !isBMissing) {
        docs.forEach(doc -> {
            doc.setA(a);
            doc.setB(b);
            saveDocument(doc);
        });
    } else if(!isBMissing) {
        docs.forEach(doc -> {
            doc.setB(b);
            saveDocument(doc);
        });
    } else if(!isAMissing) {
        docs.forEach(doc -> {
            doc.setA(a);
            saveDocument(doc);
        });
    }
}
```

I would like to know, if the size of the documents is large (100,000+), will there be a noticible difference in performance or is there some 'under the hood' optimization that the JVM does that would make it pointless to make this change?

Comment: You have the code, why don't you profile it?

Comment: performance here is less important then the cleaner code. That thing looks baaaad

Comment: First option looks more cleaner to me

Comment: I say stick with the simpler code.  For one thing, will `changeProperties` be used in other ways?  If so, either now or in the future, then you want that extra logic in there.  Also, to maybe allow you to avoid profiling...your question may be answered by asking "what does `saveDocument(doc);` do?".  If that method does much at all, the two checks before you call it will be irrelevant in comparison.